# PDF math formulas to txt

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf, pdfminer

I have lots of PDF files with text, charts, formulas in it.
[image: Example]

I wanted to find the position from the starting point to the ending point for the formulas. Using pdfminer.six and pypdf does not return the formulas in a right way. Tried the OCR tools and ScanSSD but they are way to old and gave tons of errors when setup.

Comment: What is "the right way"? What do you expect? Do you understand why this is a hard task?

Comment: can you share a sample pdf ?

Comment: getting the bbox should be straight forward (if these are images or XObjects) assuming the entire PDF isn't bunch of images

Comment: There is little you can do about this.  PDF files are not stored as words, sentences, 
and paragraphs.  There is no organization.  A PDF contains instructions like "put an S at x,y; then put an R at x,y; then put an N at x,y, etc."  It's just a record of what would be sent to a printer.  Some tools try to collect the text that's near other text, but it's not exact.

Comment: Seeing that the fraction line is drawn using many '-' characters in a row, that formula isn't really drawn to allow easy extraction...

Answer (score 0):

the Question focus is page 23 of https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/vl6180.pdf Font object # 483 `SNR RESULT __RANGE_RETURN_SIGNAL_COUNT{0x6C} RESULT__RANGE_RETURN_AMB_COUNT{0x74} * 6 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - =` so it starts with the S and ends with the = having gone around in a zigzag thus measure height as total heights and width as total widths

If you are lucky the "Figure" will have been tagged so we can see that object is MCID34

[image]

Thus we can search for its data.
Here is the smaller first part heading as the object body is many lines long.

```
EMC
/Figure <</MCID 34>>BDC
q
1 i 
129.96 685.58 391.98 -38.76 re
W* n
123.96 749.54 403.98 -102.72 re
W* n
0 841.98 595.2 -841.98 re
W n
BT
/F1 1 Tf
9 0 0 9 200.04 662.7803 Tm
.06 Tc
(SNR)Tj
3.8267 .5533 TD
[(RE)6.7(SULT)]TJ
3.9467 0 TD
0 Tc
[(__RANGE)6.7(_RETURN_S)6.7(IGNAL_CO)6.7(UNT{0x6C)6.7(})]TJ
```

so left edge is `200.04` and at a GUESS the righthand end will be `450.###`
likewise the height is roughly `654` to `675`. Normally we could not know with precision what scale the font letter would be, as it would be device specific, however here they are imbedded so are fixed dimensions.

[image]

For a programmable answer there are many applications and personally I will try MuPDF as suitable to give an accurate set of values.

```
<fill_text colorspace="DeviceGray" color="0" ri="1" bp="1" op="0" opm="1" transform="1 0 0 -1 0 842">
                <span font="JHKLGG+Courier" wmode="0" bidi="0" trm="9 0 0 9">
                    <g unicode="S" glyph="S" x="200.04" y="662.7803" adv=".6"/>
                    <g unicode="N" glyph="N" x="205.98" y="662.7803" adv=".6"/>
                    <g unicode="R" glyph="R" x="211.92" y="662.7803" adv=".6"/>
                    <g unicode="R" glyph="R" x="234.48029" y="667.75997" adv=".6"/>
                    <g unicode="E" glyph="E" x="240.42029" y="667.75997" adv=".6"/>
```

So we can say the upper left bound is `x ="200.04"` and for y `667.75997` + nominal 9 = nominally `675.75997`(you can round that down as 9 is overkill)
for the lower right bound we can use

```
 <g unicode=" " glyph="space" x="439.91856" y="656.71969" adv=".6"/>
                    <g unicode="6" glyph="six" x="445.31855" y="656.71969" adv=".6"/>
```

thus `x = 450.719` any `y = 656.720` but that y value will need rounding down for descenders, so at a guess 655 same as done by eye.

Comment: which tool is this ?

Comment: thanks! will use this next time I work with PDFs..

Answer (score 0):

One way of getting the formulas is to read the `Figures` from the raw data..
the formula you pointed is a `Figure` and is a marked text content. The way txt is rendered is to move the text position `show` text and move text position etc. All these rules are in the PDF itself. They way you want to generate text from these rules depends on how you want to consume these formulas. Following is a snippet

```
import PyPDF2
import re


if __name__ == "__main__":

    document = PyPDF2.PdfReader("vl6180.pdf")
    figures_data = []
    for i, page in enumerate(document.pages):
        print(f"Processing Page {i}")
        if isinstance(page['/Contents'].get_object(), PyPDF2.generic._data_structures.EncodedStreamObject):
            page_data = page['/Contents'].get_object().get_data().decode("utf-8", errors='ignore')
            fig_indices = [m.start() for m in re.finditer("/Figure", page_data)]
            for figure_data_start in fig_indices:
                figure_data_end = page_data[figure_data_start:].index("EMC")
                figure_raw_data = page_data[figure_data_start:figure_data_start + figure_data_end]
                figures_data.append(figure_raw_data.split("\n"))
    print(f"Found {len(figures_data)} figures")
```

```
...
Found 4 figures
```

So this is the data for one of the formulas as the text is rendered in text positions you can choose how you want to consume the formula text

```
\n/Figure <</MCID 34>>
BDC
\nq
\n1 i 
\n129.96 685.58 391.98 -38.76 re
\nW* n
\n123.96 749.54 403.98 -102.72 re
\nW* n
\n0 841.98 595.2 -841.98 re
\nW n
\nBT
\n/F1 1 Tf
\n9 0 0 9 200.04 662.7803 Tm
\n.06 Tc
\n(SNR)Tj
\n3.8267 .5533 TD\
n[(RE)6.7(SULT)]TJ\n3.9467 0 TD\n0 Tc
\n[(__RANGE)6.7(_RETURN_S)6.7(IGNAL_CO)6.7(UNT{0x6C)6.7(})]TJ
\n-4.24 -1.2267 TD\n[(R)-60(E)-60(S)-53.3(U)-60(L)-60(T)-53.3(__RANGE_)6.7(RETURN_A)6.7(MB_COUNT)6.7({0x74} *)6.7( 6)]TJ
\n0 .6733 TD
\n(-)Tj\n.3 0 TD\n(-)Tj\n.3 0 TD\n(-)Tj\n.3 0 TD\n(-)Tj\n.3 0 TD\n(-)Tj\n.3 0 TD\n(-)Tj\n.3 0 TD\n(-)Tj\n.3 0 TD\n(-)Tj\n.3 0 TD\n(-)Tj\n.3 0 TD\n(-)Tj\n.2933 0 TD\n(-)Tj\n.3 0 TD\n(-)Tj\n.3 0 TD\n(-)Tj\n.3 0 TD\n(-)Tj\n.3 0 TD\n(-)Tj\n.3 0 TD\n(-)Tj\n.3 0 TD\n(-)Tj\n.3 0 TD\n(-)Tj\n.3 0 TD\n(-)Tj\n.3 0 TD\n(-)Tj\n.3 0 TD\n(-)Tj\n.3 0 TD\n(-)Tj\n.3 0 TD\n(-)Tj\n.3 0 TD\n(-)Tj\n.3 0 TD\n(-)Tj\n.3 0 TD\n(-)Tj\n.3 0 TD\n(-)Tj\n.2933 0 TD\n(-)Tj\n.3 0 TD\n(-)Tj\n.3 0 TD\n(-)Tj\n.3 0 TD\n(-)Tj\n.3 0 TD\n(-)Tj\n.3 0 TD\n(-)Tj\n.3 0 TD\n(-)Tj\n.3 0 TD\n(-)Tj\n.3 0 TD\n(-)Tj\n.3 0 TD\n(-)Tj\n.3 0 TD\n(-)Tj\n.3 0 TD\n(-)Tj\n.3 0 TD\n(-)Tj\n.3 0 TD\n(-)Tj\n.3 0 TD\n(-)Tj\n.3 0 TD\n(-)Tj\n.2933 0 TD\n(-)Tj\n.3 0 TD\n(-)Tj\n.3 0 TD\n(-)Tj\n.3 0 TD\n(-)Tj\n.3 0 TD\n(-)Tj\n.3 0 TD\n(-)Tj\n.3 0 TD\n(-)Tj\n.3 0 TD\n(-)Tj\n.3 0 TD\n(-)Tj\n.3 0 TD\n(-)Tj\n.3 0 TD\n(-)Tj\n.3 0 TD\n(-)Tj\n.3 0 TD\n(-)Tj\n.3 0 TD\n(-)Tj\n.3 0 TD\n(-)Tj\n.3 0 TD\n(-)Tj\n.3 0 TD\n(-)Tj\n.2933 0 TD\n(-)Tj\n.3 0 TD\n(-)Tj\n.3 0 TD\n(-)Tj\n.3 0 TD\n(-)Tj\n.3 0 TD\n(-)Tj\n.3 0 TD\n(-)Tj\n.3 0 TD\n(-)Tj\n.3 0 TD\n(-)Tj\n.3 0 TD\n(-)Tj\n.3 0 TD\n(-)Tj\n.3 0 TD\n(-)Tj\n.3 0 TD\n(-)Tj\n.3 0 TD\n(-)Tj\n.3 0 TD\n(-)Tj\n.3 0 TD\n(-)Tj\n.3 0 TD\n(-)Tj\n.2933 0 TD\n(-)Tj\n.3 0 TD\n(-)Tj\n.3 0 TD\n(-)Tj\n.3 0 TD\n(-)Tj\n.0533 0 TD\n(-)Tj
\n-24.84 0 TD
\n(=)Tj\nET
\nEMC
```

Some more documentation::

```
Text Matrix (Tm): The text matrix is set to define the transformation for text rendering, including scaling, rotation, and translation


Move Text Position (Td or TD): Adjust the text position using either Td (relative) or TD (absolute)


Show Text (Tj or TJ): Display the actual text using either Tj (show text) or TJ (show text with explicit glyph positioning)
```

Note:: TD /Td will be before the Tj
Imagine this like any other rendering software